# How to link reusable ExtendedFloatingActionButton with reusable Scaffold

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

**Expected result:**

Reusable `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` should expand or collapse within a reusable `Scaffold` when I scroll.

**Current result:**

`ExtendedFloatingActionButton` does not expand or collapse when I scroll the list in my `Scaffold`

I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@patrickmillais/collapsible-extended-floating-action-buttons-with-a-lazycolumn-in-jetpack-compose-a5909fada6a1), but it was not created with reusability in mind. The part I'm confused about is the `listState` varible within the section called "Joining Everything Together" because I'm not sure where within my code I need to declare it as I have done this a few times in different areas.

```
@Composable
fun MyReusableScaffold(scaffoldTitle: String, scaffoldFab: @Composable () -> Unit,
                        scaffoldContent: @Composable (contentPadding: PaddingValues) -> Unit) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { LargeTopAppBar( title = { Text(text = scaffoldTitle) } ) },
        floatingActionButton = { scaffoldFab },
        content = { contentPadding -> scaffoldContent(contentPadding = contentPadding) }
    )
}

@Composable
fun MyFAB(listState: LazyListState) {
    ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
        text = { Text(text = "title") },
        icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "") },
        expanded = listState.isScrollingUp()
    )
}

@Composable
fun <T> MyLazyColumn(modifier: Modifier,
...
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyColumn(
        state = listState
    ) {
        ...
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyHomeScreen() {
    MyScaffold(
        scaffoldTitle = "title",
        scaffoldFab = MyExtendedFAB(listState = LazyListState?)
        scaffoldContent = { MyHomeScreenContent(contentPadding = it) },
    )
}

@Composable
fun MyHomeScreenContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues()
) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expansion state of the `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` is managed by the `expanded`.

In your example the expanded state is derived on the `listState` of the `LazyColumn`. It means that `LazyColumn` and `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` **have to use** both the same `listState`.

For example you can do something like:

```
@Composable
fun MyHomeScreen() {

    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    val expandedFab by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            listState.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0
        }
    }

    MyReusableScaffold(
        scaffoldTitle = "title",
        scaffoldFab = { MyFAB(expandedFab) },
        scaffoldContent = { MyHomeScreenContent(contentPadding = it, listState = listState) },
    )
}

fun MyFAB(expandedFab : Boolean) {

    ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
        //...
        expanded = expandedFab
    )
}

@Composable
fun MyLazyColumn(modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
                listState: LazyListState
) {
    LazyColumn(
        state = listState
    ) { /** ... */ }
}

@Composable
fun MyHomeScreenContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    listState: LazyListState,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues()
) {
    MyLazyColumn( listState = listState )
}
```

Comment: Whenever I want to use `MyLazyColumn` for the content of my screen, do I need to use `LazyListState` for the `listState`? For example, `listState = LazyListState`